# nginx catchall reurns bad gate way with $host in proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, rewrite, reverse-proxy

I am currently using the following virtual server proxy setup  on my development environment the defined virtual servers work fine but i am coming up with a bad gateway error when i hit my catchall

The idea is to use nginx as a front end to run IIS Apache and Tomcat side by side on port 80 and use IIS (port 88 in my setup) as a default  for the catchall rule

This also allows me to proxy out any thing I need from our production or testing servers without having to maintain a 60gb stash of content files in my local environment or worry about tunneling into our test server environment through a virtual directory

(we don't use a CDN currently due to legacy code changes needed to support it)

I want it to catch the defined urls and configure their proxys other wise just pass the url on to IIS

So my big question here is why is this resulting in a bad gateway error and how to fix it to work properly or am I abusing the system here, I am somewhat new to nginx and haven't been able find anything similar through exhaustive google and SE searches

```
   server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  m.dev.someurl.com;

            location / {
              proxy_pass      http://m.dev.someurl.com:88;
              proxy_redirect  http://m.dev.someurl.com:88/ /;
              proxy_read_timeout 60s;

              # May not need or want to set Host. Should default to the above hostname.
              proxy_set_header          Host            $host;
              proxy_set_header          X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            }

            location /Content {
              proxy_pass      http://m.productionserver.com/Content;
              proxy_redirect  http://m.productionserver.com/Content/ /;
              proxy_read_timeout 60s;

              # May not need or want to set Host. Should default to the above hostname.
              proxy_set_header          Host            $host;
              proxy_set_header          X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            }
    }



    server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            #server_name _;

            location / {
              proxy_pass      http://$host:88;
              proxy_redirect  http://$host:88/ /;
              proxy_read_timeout 60s;

              # May not need or want to set Host. Should default to the above hostname.
              proxy_set_header          Host            $host;
              proxy_set_header          X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            }


    }
```

log entries similar to this are generated when the catchall should be getting hit 
please note all the urls used are referenced in the hosts file to resolve locally

```
2015/02/12 11:16:20 [error] 1248#8412: *2 no resolver defined to resolve dev.serverurl.ca, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /Content/Utility/TickerUpdate HTTP/1.1", host: "dev.serverurl.ca", referrer: "http://dev.serverurl.ca/somefolder"
```

Comment: What is `http://$host:88` supposed to do? Also you shouldn't use port 88 as that is reserved for Kerberos.

Comment: my IIS sites are running on port 88 with url bindings which is where i want my default route to proxy the hostname

Comment: the port isn't important i can use whatever if 88 is reserved for kerberos i can change that fairly quickly

Comment: I mean, why are you using `$host`? That just makes your server an open proxy and ripe for abuse. If you mean to proxy to a local IIS, why not just address it by localhost or IP address?

Comment: did you actually read my post?

I want to run several web servers side by side on port 80 ie IIS and Apache and Tomcat hence why I am using reverse proxy

Comment: as i mentioned as well i am new to this if there is a better way to  set this up let me know and my theoretical thinking iis would only bind to the host name defined on the site if the the user passed an undefined host this should theoretically just fail the request should it not

Comment: Did you read error message? It's clearly states that `no resolver defined`